# Why is my multi-threading program in VirtualBox not faster than my single-thread program?

Tags: c, multithreading, operating-system, montecarlo, pi

everybody!
I have two program estimating PI using Monte-Carlo technique : one using single-thread and one using multi-thread.

The single-thread one :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define BILLION 1000000000.0

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct timespec start, end;
    ///////////////////////
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &start);
    ///////////////////////
    if(argc != 2)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "usage: a.out <integer value>\n");
        return -1;
    }
    
    if(atoi(argv[1]) < 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%d must be >= 0\n", atoi(argv[1]));
        return -1;
    }
    time_t t;
    srand((unsigned) time(&t));
    int total = atoi(argv[1]);
    int inside = 0;
    unsigned int seed = rand()%30000;
    for(int i = 0; i < total; ++i)
    {
        double rand_x = (double)rand_r(&seed)/(double)RAND_MAX;
        double rand_y = (double)rand_r(&seed)/(double)RAND_MAX;
        
        double dist = rand_x*rand_x + rand_y*rand_y;
        if(dist < 1.0) ++inside;
    } 
   
    double pi = (double)(4 * inside)/total;
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &end);
    double time_spent = (end.tv_sec - start.tv_sec) + (end.tv_nsec - start.tv_nsec) / BILLION;
    printf("pi = %lf\n", pi);
    printf("time = %f\n", time_spent);
    return 0;
}
```

The multi-thread one:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <math.h>

#define N 5
#define BILLION 1000000000.0
int inside = 0;

pthread_mutex_t mutex;


void* countInside(void * n)
{
    int total = (int)n;
    int hit_count = 0;
    unsigned int seed = rand()%30000;
    for(int i = 0; i < total; ++i)
    {
        double rand_x = (double)rand_r(&seed)/(double)RAND_MAX;
        double rand_y = (double)rand_r(&seed)/(double)RAND_MAX;
        
        double dist = rand_x*rand_x + rand_y*rand_y;
        if(dist < 1.0) ++hit_count;
    }
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    inside += hit_count;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    pthread_exit(0);
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct timespec start, end;
    ///////////////////////
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &start);
    ///////////////////////
    if(argc != 2)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "usage: a.out <integer value>\n");
        return -1;
    }
    
    if(atoi(argv[1]) < 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%d must be >= 0\n", atoi(argv[1]));
        return -1;
    }
    
    int total = atoi(argv[1]);

    srand((unsigned) time(NULL));
    //int N;
    //printf("Input the number of thread you desire : ");
    //scanf("%d", &N);
    int n = total/N;
    //pthread_t* tid = malloc(sizeof(pthread_t) * (N));
    pthread_t tid[N];
    pthread_mutex_init(&mutex, NULL);
    for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {
        pthread_create(&tid[i], 0, countInside, (void*)n);
    }
    
    for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {
        pthread_join(tid[i], NULL);
    }
    double pi = 4.0 * inside / total;
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &end);
    double time_spent = (end.tv_sec - start.tv_sec) + (end.tv_nsec - start.tv_nsec) / BILLION;
    printf("pi = %lf\n", pi);
    printf("time = %lf\n", time_spent);
    return 0;
}
```

When i execute both program with 100000000 points, i get the ouput:
Ouput of single-thread:

```
quan@quan-VirtualBox:~/Documents/lab5$ ./pi_serial 100000000
pi = 3.141583
time = 1.576207
```

Output of multi-thread:

```
quan@quan-VirtualBox:~/Documents/lab5$ ./pi_multi-thread 100000000
pi = 3.141532
time = 1.446410
```

Note : There are sometimes multi-thread one is even slower than single-thread one.

What's the problem ? I thought multi-thread must have some speed-up compared to single-thread one. Is my multi-thread code wrong ? Please give me some advice? Thank you!

Comment: You're running on a VirtualBox. Do you have multiple cores enabled?

Comment: Thank you! That is exactly my problem! After i enable multiple cores, the multi-thread one  become much faster!